# Is it possible to gain control on the amount of objects created when deserializing a file

Tags: java, performance, serialization, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

Suppose I have a file with a lot (most likely 100K+, potentially millions) of serialized objects of the same class. I read these objects and do something with them:

```
//open stream
try{ 
    while(true) {
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        foo(o);
    }
}catch(EOFException){
}
//close stream...
```

When this is done, a very uncomfortably large amount of objects have been created. My problem is that I don't have control of those objects, and they won't be freed until the GC decides to do it.

Is there a way to put an upper limit on the amount of new objects created? For example, if my file has 100K serialized objects, is there a way to tweak the readObject mechanism so that a fixed size pool is used?

## More Details

The ~100K object file is the merged result of many smaller files. What this small process is doing, is to create a sorted CSV file.

Comment: This is your code, right?  Count the number of objects created, and stop when the count reaches 100,000.

Comment: Try looking for these methods writeReplace() and readResolve() And check this link:
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=44039

Comment: @Piro I do need the objects. Particularly, foo will convert them into a cvs format. I need every one of them, but cant afford to have each and every one of them in memory.

Comment: Then you'll need to write them to a file... which is kinda back where you started.

Comment: readResolve will not help, since it is working on created object. Only thing i can think of is to not serialize whole objects, just data, but it is almost as writing directly to csv.

Comment: How about using a weak reference that is referenced until the `foo` method ends ?

Answer (score 2):

None of the suggested comments or answers so far will work (most of them are also unnecessary), because the `ObjectInputStream` itself holds a reference to every object it has ever deserialized, for preservation of object graphs.

You need to constrain how much data is *written* to the file, so you don't have to handle 100,000 objects per file, and if possible you should also make use of `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` or `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()`, for the reasons described in their respective Javadoc comments.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Elaborate what, exactly?

Comment: Why would the ObjectInputStream hold references indefinitely?

Comment: Because of the handle system. If you serialize the same Object twice with no intervening reset(), it will serialize a handle for the second occurrence, and deserialization will produce one object, two references. This is essential for preserving potentially cyclic object graphs during serialization, which is one of Object Serialization's major advantages over its competitors. To implement that, the ObjectInputStream has to retain memory, until it encounters a reset in the stream, produced by ObjectOutputStream.reset(), whereupon it clears its memory.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your answer. A couple of doubts.
1) reset() will only free retained memory if objects are written with writeObject() right? Seems unnecesary if they are written with writeUnshared().
2) Should `readUnshared()` be used to read from the serialized file without retaining memory?
3) Any reason for OptionalDataExceptions? Can`t pinpoint the cause, but they appear when reading.

Comment: reset() frees everything. writeUnshared() writes the object itself without sharing, but any referenced objects are still shared. OptionalDataException could indicate something wrong with a custom readObject()/writeObject() pair in one of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a fixed-sized collection of PhantomReferences to each of the objects from the file.

Once the collection is full, you only read another object from the file if and only if an existing PhantomReference can be retrieved/removed (as a blocking call) from the ReferenceQueue, after which you remove it from the fixed-sized collection and allow another to be created.

Remember to call 'clear()' on the PhantomReference after you remove it from the ReferenceQueue.

Hope this helps!

Refer to this document for more information regarding Phantom References: 
https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kcpeppe/archive/2011/09/29/mysterious-phantom-reference

And Here:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/finalization-and-phantom

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also have some influence on the design of the program that wrote those serialized objects. Isn't this kind of problem suggesting that the Java serialization format is not a good fit for your problem?  Perhaps you should write and read the objects in some other format, which allows you to discard old objects as garbage during processing of the stream?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to read Objects, you have to create Objects, there is little you can do about this. Changing your code to `foo(ois.readObject());` gives the compiler a hint that it doesn't need to store the reference, but still Objects are created.

That leaves you two options:

1. You trust the Garbage Collector to be highly efficient and well designed.
2. You change your underlying data structure to not store Objects, but design it in a form that completely relies on primitive data types.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, EJP proposed to regenerate your input files using `writeUnshared` technique instead of `writeObject` to make object available for GC during reading. If it's about regenerating original content, then may be you could switch to some other serializer like [Kryo](https://code.google.com/p/kryo/wiki/V1Benchmarks)?

> Java's built-in serialization is slow, inefficient, and has many well-known problems (see Effective Java, by Josh Bloch pp. 213).

Their promised serialized object size is 5x smaller than standard Java's, so memory consumption should be at least 5x smaller, I think.

**EDIT**

Better wording: 5x-7x heavier serialized objects most probably mean that `ObjectInputStream` is a memory eater, e.g. uses too much for the job, though frees that memory in the end.

Comment: That doesn't follow at all. The object is still the object. What's in the file isn't retained in memory, and doesn't affect the size of the object in memory either.

Comment: The inefficient serialized Java stuff need be read to somewhere which  is GC-collected memory. Yes, the resulting memory consumption is the same, because it's being GC-freed in the end, but in the middle the load is much higher. Unneeded memory allocation must be the most significant factor for why the built-in deserialization is [36x times slower](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki) than Kryo.

Comment: 'In the middle the load is much higher' why? You read some bytes from a stream, create an object, and throw the bytes away. Repeat 100,000 times. The total memory consumption is then the space occupies by the 100,000 objects. The fact that the bytes are 1/5 the size doesn't reduce the total memory consumption by 80% as you claimed. The speed improvement you refer to is far more likely to come from reduced I/O than this alleged reduced memory consumption.

Comment: This was my very guess - if the size is only 5-7 times greater, then why is speed the 30x slower? Because of unnecessary buffer copying? Reflection instead of Unsafe usage? My bet is on small object allocations and I'll setup an experiment tomorrow. :-)

Comment: I'm not concerned about that. I'm concerned about the error in your answer where you claim the memory is reduced by 80% because the disk size is reduced by 80%. It doesn't make sense, and it isn't so.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking this statement is not always true, but it's the case, I presume.

Comment: No it isn't. You still have 100,000 deserialized objects,whose size doesn't change. The memory consumed by the bytes read per object to deserialize each one is GC-able after each object is deserialized, and cannot therefore be responsible for an 80% memory savings. You haven't addressed this point. I can't make head or tail of your edit. DataInputStream isn't a memory eater.

Comment: I didn't and this was not the problem for the topic starter. The problem was with many objects allocated during deser. Anyway, updated to be more precise.

Comment: It isn't 'more precise'. It is still exactly the same as before. The size of a serialized object has no effect on the size of the resulting deserialized object. What comes out of the deserialization must be the same as what goes into the serialization. Your assertion of a 5x memory saving is complete fantasy.

Comment: It's not a 'memory saving' measurement, it's the memory allocation measurement I'm talking about and it's what the TS was concerned about. So the algorithm or framework can be almost GC friendly like Kryo/Disruptor/Mentaqueue or it's performance can suffer from too many memory allocations like `ObjectInputStream` or `LinkedBlockingQueue`. Usually this is achieved by reusing already allocated objects - i.e. object pools or cyclic buffers.